# Программа меняет буквы в слове

Tags: pascal

Нужно поменять местами первую и последнюю буквы каждого слова. Помогите, пожалуйста. Пол дня мучаюсь, но дошла лишь до:

```
Var
i,t,p: Integer;
n:byte;
s,z,c: String;
Begin
writeln('Vvelite stroku');
readln(s);
n:=length(s);

p:=Pos(' ',S);
if p<>0 then
begin
z:=s[1];
c:=copy(s,p-1,1);
delete(s,p-1,1);
insert(z,s,p-1);
delete(s,1,1);
insert(c,s,1);
end;
```

Как дальше быть?

Comment: Судя потому, что у Вас уже есть, Вы не до конца понимаете, что происходит в Вашем коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вам необходим цикл, в котором вы будете искать индекс пробельного символа. Кроме того, задумайтесь над тем, что не только пробел может быть в конце слова, а еще несколько различных знаков. Для вашей задачи использовать функцию `Pos` особого смысла не имеет. Например,

```
for I := 1 to length(s) do
    begin
        if (s[i] = ' ') or (s[i] = ',') or ... then
            ...
    end;
```

Во-вторых, использование функций `copy, insert, delete` так же бессмысленно. Так как строка представлена массивом символов, вам лишь нужно поменять значения по индексу первой буквы слова и ваш текущий индекс в поиске минус один. Таким образом:

```
var 
    c: char;
    firstLetter: integer;//в начале работы программы должна быть = 1 
    //(самому первому символу строки)

...//нашли пробел/другой символ
c = s[firstLetter]; //сохраняем первую букву слова
s[firstLetter] := s[i - 1]; //перезапиписываем первую букву последней
s[i - 1] := c; //перезаписываем последнюю букву
//сохраняем первую букву следующего слова, 
//не забыв проверить не вышли ли мы за пределы длины строки
if (i + 1) <= length(s) then //если i + 1 будет больше, мы и так из цикла выйдем
    firstLetter = i + 1;
```

Можно все это еще сдобрить проверками различного рода, когда несколько пробелов подряд, например. С индексами будьте аккуратны, я мог что-то где-то упустить, ведь описывал просто один из вариантов решения.

Comment: Функции `pos`, `insert`, `delete` и `copy` есть в Паскале.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!
firstLetter:=1

Comment: А что говорит отладчик? Чему равно `i` во время ошибки?

Comment: НО если задать изначально, что i:=2 ошибку не выдает, но не выводит ответ

Comment: Я же писал, что при `i := 1` все замечательно работает. Вы отладчиком пользовались?

Comment: эмм..неет.

Comment: Зря, он вам покажет, где у вас ошибка.

Comment: он показывает, что прграмма сразу же стопорится на s[firstLetter] := s[i - 1];  , на первом i

Comment: Это не желательно делать по правилам форума, если хотите реально разобраться, напишите мне в skype, контакты в профиле.

Answer (score 1):

Так Вы поменяете местами первую и последнюю букву у первого слова в строке (если строка не начинается с пробела).

Чтобы сделать это со всеми словами, нужно организовать цикл по условию "пока в строке есть не обработанное слово". Но так делать не надо.

Проще пройти по всей строке одним циклом и руками собирать слова по символу.

Comment: по условию все слова разделены только пробелом и только одним.  Есть проблема: s[firstLetter] := s[i - 1];  на этой строке появляется сообщение - "Индекс находился вне границ массива", программа прекращается.  и появляется это сообщение каждый раз при подобных записях s[f]:=[i+1],s[f]:=[i-1]  и т.п.

Comment: к сожалению это ничеко не изменило.Ошибка времени выполнения:Индекс находился вне границ массива.

Comment: Все работает (снимаю предыдущий комментарий). Смотрите на индексы, ищите, где вы допустили ошибку. Мне не сложно выложить рабочий код, но я его уже выложил выше, только что еще и проверил.

Comment: запускаю через pascalabc ну тоооочно все перепроверила, уже даже понимаю в идеале код. но на строчке s[firstLetter] := s[i - 1]; всю тужу самую ошиюку выдает(

Comment: пардон *ошибку

Comment: а firstLetter чему равен?